# C# enum to postgres enum

Tags: c#, postgresql, enums, npgsql

I am currently using postgres enum

```
CREATE TYPE http_action_enum AS ENUM ('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'CONNECT', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE', 'PATCH');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS response
(
    id                          UUID                PRIMARY KEY,
    http_action                 http_action_enum    NOT NULL
);
```

But when I using the ef framework to insert to postgres database I keep hit the below error:

```
Exception data:
Severity: ERROR
SqlState: 42804
MessageText: column "destination" is of type source_dest_enum but expression is of type integer
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

When I check the response data type it is actually the correct enum and not integer.

Repository.cs

```
public async Task<Response> InsertRecord(Response response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      await dBContext.response.AddAsync(response, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);
      await dBContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);

      return response;
}
```

DBContext.cs

```
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
            modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<SourceDestinationEnum>();
            modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<HttpActionEnum>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Response>().Property(d => d.RespondedData).HasColumnType("json");
```

HttpActionEnum.cs

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum HttpActionEnum
    {
        GET,
        POST,
    }
```

Does anyone come across mapping c# enum to postgres enum and could advice?

I tried converting to an enum but it's failing with an error that say the column is of type enum but expression is of type text.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

DBContext.cs (updated)

```
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
            modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<SourceDestinationEnum>();
            modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<HttpActionEnum>();

           modelBuilder.Entity<Response>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.RespondedData).HasColumnType("json");
                entity.Property(e => e.Destination).HasConversion(
                    v => v.ToString(),
                    v => (SourceDestinationEnum)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(SourceDestinationEnum), v));
            });
```

Error

```
+       InnerException  {"42804: column \"destination\" is of type source_dest_enum but expression is of type text"}    System.Exception {Npgsql.PostgresException}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the entity framework article about postgres enums here: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1

> Even if your database enum is created, Npgsql has to know about it, and especially about your CLR enum type that should be mapped to it. This is done by adding the following code, before any EF Core operations take place. An appropriate place for this is in the static constructor on your DbContext class:

```
static MyDbContext()
    => NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Mood>();
```

For non EF situations check information here: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html

Comment: Hi @Athansios, I tried adding the static constructor or overriding the OnConfiguring but it keeps fails and throw an exception that `{"The CLR enum type SourceDestinationEnum must be registered with Npgsql before usage, please refer to the documentation."}`

Comment: Try removing the HasConversion to which converts to string.

Comment: I tried removing the HasConversion, but it still prompted me `{"The CLR enum type SourceDestinationEnum must be registered with Npgsql before usage, please refer to the documentation."}` I added some snippet to share with you to see if you have any idea where I had made mistake. https://gist.github.com/weihan1394/fdb2990c0b4ad5680d4c3f11a8e9c8d4

Comment: You definitely seem to be mixing several modes. If you want your C# enums to be mapped to PostgreSQL enums, you need to follow https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1 (see the full sample there which works). If you want to map your C# enums to PostgreSQL text, you can use a value converter (in which case remove all the HasPostgresEnum directives, etc.)

Comment: I happened to use `NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum` but it is marked obsolete on Npgsql 7. What should be my approach?

Answer (score 0):

If the enum just needs to be converted to a string, something like this should work:

```
var converter = new EnumToStringConverter<HttpActionEnum>();

modelBuilder
    .Entity<Response>()
    .Property(e => e.RespondedData)
    .HasConversion(converter);
```

Comment: Hi @Colin, thank you for your help! But after i converted it to a string, it prompted me similar problem `MessageText: column "destination" is of type source_dest_enum but expression is of type text`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue in a WebApi application. I had to move the below line to Startup.cs `ConfigureServices()` method.

```
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Mood>();
```