# npgsql The CLR enum type must be registered with Npgsql before usage

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, enums, npgsql

I am trying to map my enum at my DBContext but it keeps show and error that my enum type is not registered with Npgsql. I have already registered at the static method but it shows an error that my enum is not registered by the clr is there anything i missed out?

**Error**

```
---> System.NotSupportedException: The CLR enum type enumsetone must be registered with Npgsql before usage, please refer to the documentation.
```

**DBContext.cs**

```
public virtual DbSet<Response> response { get; set; }

static void RegisterTypes()
{
       NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<enumsetone>();
       NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<enumsettwo>();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
       modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
       modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<enumsetone>();
       modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<enumsettwo>();
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       DBContext.RegisterTypes();
       services.AddDbContextPool<DBContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresSqlDb")));
}
```

**Enumsetone.cs**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Enumsetone
{
    GET,
    POST
}
```

**Response.cs**

```
[Table("response", Schema = "public")]
public class Response
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid ResponseId { get; set; }
    [Column("source")]
    public enumsetone Source { get; set; }
    [Column("destination")]
    public enumsetone Destination { get; set; }
    [Column("status_code")]
    public enumsettwo EnumSetTwo { get; set; }
        
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# enum to postgres enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590759/c-sharp-enum-to-postgres-enum)

Comment: @ShayRojansky it didn't resolve the problem still. Currently, using a shared enum for 2 variables in a class file. Not sure if this is the reason that caused the problem. :(

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand - the above code shows two different enum types, rather than a the same enum used by two variables... Can you maybe post a simple console app that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @ShayRojansky Sorry for the mistake in the code, I have updated the code that reflects the scenario given

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar proble on EF Core 5.0. ORM uses default name translator (which is PaskalCase to snake_case) to get the name of the postgres enum type. In your example name of the enum is Enumsetone so postgres type should have name enumsetone. You can check the name by invoking

`string name = NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.DefaultNameTranslator.TranslateTypeName(typeof(YourEnum).Name);`