# Create Postgresql enum type and binary import with Npgsql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

Using Npgsql, I am trying to create a Postgresql enum type and then to do a binary import from .NET.

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="7.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Source file:

```
using Npgsql;

var connectionString =
  "Host=localhost;" +
  "Port=5432;" +
  "Username=postgres;" +
  "Password=postgres;" +
  "Database=test_db;";

using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();

var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText =
  "create type mood as enum ('happy', 'sad');" +
  "create table people (age integer, cmood mood);";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

var copyCmd =
  "copy people (age, cmood)" +
  "from stdin (format binary)";

using var writer = connection.BeginBinaryImport(copyCmd);

writer.StartRow();
writer.Write(12);
writer.Write(Mood.Happy);
writer.Complete();

enum Mood
{
  Null = 0,
  Sad = 1,
  Happy = 2
}
```

Of course, a Postgresql server is running on my machine and an empty database `test_db` has been created. Executing the above program results in a `System.ArgumentException` ("A PostgreSQL type with the name `mood` was not found in the database"). However, querying the database from the command line shows that the type has been created exactly when expected, i.e. after executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` in the above listing.

Why is the binary import failing and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591371/7731398) answer to a related question, I ended up on
[this](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1) entity framework article about postgres enums where I found out that I needed a single line `connection.ReloadTypes();` to make my program work!

Complete working program (just one line is different!):

```
using Npgsql;

var connectionString =
  "Host=localhost;" +
  "Port=5432;" +
  "Username=postgres;" +
  "Password=postgres;" +
  "Database=test_db;";

using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();

var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText =
  "create type mood as enum ('happy', 'sad');" +
  "create table people (age integer, cmood mood);";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

connection.ReloadTypes();

var copyCmd =
  "copy people (age, cmood)" +
  "from stdin (format binary)";

using var writer = connection.BeginBinaryImport(copyCmd);

writer.StartRow();
writer.Write(12);
writer.Write(Mood.Happy);
writer.Complete();

enum Mood
{
  Null = 0,
  Sad = 1,
  Happy = 2
}
```